# How to show the selected listview item with image and text on bottom (Android View)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xamarin.android

I am very new to android UI design. 
I have ListView and I am using an adapter to inflate the view with image and text. And I am using JSON data to populate the ListView.
Which I have implemented so far.

I am not really sure which type of control is used for an application like any podcast related apps which shows the list of items and on the selection of the item, it shows the bottom bar with that item. like in this image below (red highlighted)

App Image

[image]

Just like in that image, I want to have in my application.

What is that control called and how to implement the same behaviour??
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Rupa, as for your question, I think an additional view should be placed on the bottom with image, description and all info elements which you want to display. Then you set a onclicklistener and update the view with the clicked list. I personally don&#39;t think it&#39;s a control type (although I can be wrong), I think a view should be enough. However, it depends on what sort of functionality you want behind it

Comment: Hi, if my answer works for you or not, please leave me a comment!

Comment: @JoeLv thank you very much for your time and suggestions.That works as I expected. you saved my day!

Comment: @Nero thank you very much, your idea was right, saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is that control called

Like @Nero has said, you just need an additional view on the bottom. You can create the control which you want to find easily by yourself.

---

> how to implement the same behavior

Two steps based on your project:

- In `ListView`'s layout, you need put a `View` below or over the `ListView`.
- Override the `IOnItemClickListener`.

---

### Here is a demo below.

`Main.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_ll"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_iv_start"
            android:src="@drawable/qq"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_tv"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_iv_end"
            android:src="@drawable/qq"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, the `Relativelayout` is the root view, so you can put the bottom bar over your `listview`

---

`MainActivity` and `MyAdapter`:

```
namespace Podcast
{
    [Activity(Label = "Podcast", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnItemClickListener
    {
        ListView mListView;
        ImageView mIv_start, mIv_end;
        TextView mtv;
        List<Item> list;
        public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            mtv.Text = list[position].tv;
            mIv_start.SetImageResource( list[position].iv_start);
            mIv_end.SetImageResource(list[position].iv_end);
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            list = new List<Item>();
            Item item = new Item();
            item.iv_start= Resource.Drawable.rr;
            item.iv_end = Resource.Drawable.rr;
            item.tv = "textview0";
            list.Add(item);
            Item item1 = new Item();
            item1.iv_start = Resource.Drawable.capture;
            item1.iv_end = Resource.Drawable.capture;
            item1.tv = "textview1";
            list.Add(item1);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);
            list.Add(item);

            mIv_end = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.bottom_iv_end);
            mIv_start = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.bottom_iv_start);
            mtv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.bottom_tv);
            mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv);
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
            mListView.Adapter = myAdapter;
               
            mListView.OnItemClickListener=this;
            
        }
        
    }

    public class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<Item>
    {
        Activity mContext;
        List<Item> mList;
        public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Item> list)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mList = list;

        }

        public override Item this[int position] => mList[position];

        public override int Count => mList.Count;

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
            if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
                view = mContext.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Item, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_tv).Text = mList[position].tv;
            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.item_iv_start).SetImageResource(mList[position].iv_start);
            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.item_iv_end).SetImageResource(mList[position].iv_end);
            return view;


        }
    }
}
```

In `OnItemClick` method, you can change the bottom bar when you click the listview item.

---

`Item`:

```
namespace Podcast
{
   public class Item
    {
        public int iv_start,iv_end;
        public string tv;
    }
}
```

---

`Item.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_ll"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/qq"
        android:id="@+id/item_iv_start"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_tv"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/qq"
        android:id="@+id/item_iv_end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Note:

You can control your bottom bar's visibility to achieve your project's requirement(The bottom bar will not be visible only when you click the ListView's item).